# Different ads on every website on multisite environment

Tags: functions, multisite, ads

I am using following code to insert ad in article, after 8th paragraph, through functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
  
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
      
    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';
  
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 8, $content );
    }
      
    return $content;
}
   
   
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
  
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
  
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
      
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Every webisite on network has different ad code, but in the same time I am using same theme on all sites, thus - only one functions.php file. I know I can create multiple child-themes for every installation, but that is not an option here.

Is there any way to use above code for multisite environment, but to add code to only one, general functions.php file?

Thank you...

Comment: I'm not adding an answer as this is just a plugin suggestion. Have you heard of this plugin? https://wpclips.net/adding-custom-code-in-wp-multisite/

Comment: @Lisa thank you - I already used this plugin on other projects, and Code Snippets plugin as well. In this case I only can arrange this through functions.php file, without plugin usage.

Comment: Sorry! Wish I could help more.

Comment: @Lisa thanx :) I appreciate

Comment: Why don't you add an option for the theme to provide the AD account ID.

Then, you retrieve the ID for each site and run the AD code for each site, but now you're loading the identifier that makes them different via a variable that you've pulled from each site's settings.  This way you're still just running one function for the theme and can re-use that function site-to-site.

Comment: @TonyDjukic thanx, but here is in question perticular advertiser, not AdSense, so there's no account ID, just various codes, per domain.

Comment: The solution is still the same, you'd just provide an input where you can add the various codes in whole rather than adding just the ID number.  Careful to properly sanitize and secure the code snippets.